# Query field across multiple django models

Tags: django

I want to create a "What's New" section that lists all of the database changes in the last day.  I've added an "updated" field to my models:

```
class Film(models.Model):
   .
   .
   .
   updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

class Actor(models.Model):
   .
   .
   .
   updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
```

Now I want to query across all of my models to get a date-sorted list of the most recent changes.  How do I query the "updated" field across multiple models?  Is this the most efficient way to achieve the primary purpose?

What if I wanted to be more specific and list the actual field that was altered within each model?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know of any way to run a select across multiple tables… So, unless you want to use my suggestion below, you'll just have to loop across all 'updatable' models.

However, you might want to consider having an `UpdatedItems` model, which might be something like:

```
class ItemUpdate(m.Model):
    when = m.DateTimeField(...)
    instance = m.GenericForeignKey(...)
    field = m.CharField(...)
    old_value = m.CharField(...)
    new_value = m.CharField(...)
```

Then use the  `post_save` signal to populate it:

```
form django.db.models.signals import post_save
def handle_post_save(sender, instance, *args, **kwargs):
    ItemUpdate(instance=instance, ...).save()
```

I don't know off the top of my head how to figure out which fields are updated… But I'm sure someone's asked about it on Google.